# Yii - Using find inside a derived ActiveRecord class

Tags: php, activerecord, yii

here is my Model:

```
class MyTable extends CActiveRecord{
  ...
  public function myOwnFunction{
    ...
    $this->find($myCriteria, $myParams);

    $myLocalVar = $this->MyTableColumn;
    ...
  }
}
```

My objective is to retrieve the record inside a function of MyTable CActiveRecord class

If I echo myLocalVar I find it empty

I guess I'm making a philosophical error... What is it? And what's the correct way to reach my objecive, if there is one?

Comment: Try this inside `myOwnFunction()`, `self::model()->find($myCriteria, $myParams)` or `MyTable::model()->find($myCriteria, $myParams)` and see what happens

Comment: Do you return the model at the function? Give us  more details